# numpy.unique gives wrong output for list of sets

Tags: python, list, numpy, set

I have a list of sets given by,

```
sets1 = [{1},{2},{1}]
```

When I find the unique elements in this list using numpy's `unique`, I get

```
np.unique(sets1)
Out[18]: array([{1}, {2}, {1}], dtype=object)
```

As can be seen seen, the result is wrong as `{1}` is repeated in the output.

When I change the order in the input by making similar elements adjacent, this doesn't happen.

```
sets2 = [{1},{1},{2}]

np.unique(sets2)
Out[21]: array([{1}, {2}], dtype=object)
```

Why does this occur? Or is there something wrong in the way I have done?

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but I suspect it has to do with the fact that ```sets1.sort()``` doesn't change the order of the list. I think you need to create a function ```f``` to sort the sets based on whatever criteria you want, and then pass ```sets1.sort(key=f)``` to ```np.unique()```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What happens here is that the `np.unique` function is based on the `np._unique1d` function from NumPy (see the code [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py)), which itself uses the `.sort()` method.

Now, sorting a list of sets that contain only one integer in each set **will not** result in a list with each set ordered by the value of the integer present in the set. So we will have (and that is not what we want):

```
sets = [{1},{2},{1}]
sets.sort()
print(sets)

# > [{1},{2},{1}]
# ie. the list has not been "sorted" like we want it to
```

Now, as you have pointed out, if the list of sets is already ordered in the way you want, `np.unique` will work (since you would have sorted the list beforehand).

One specific solution (though, please be aware that it will only work for a list of sets that each contain a single integer) would then be:

```
np.unique(sorted(sets, key=lambda x: next(iter(x))))
```

Answer (score -1):

That is because set is unhashable type

```
{1} is {1} # will give False
```

you can use python `collections.Counter` if you can can convert the set to tuple like below

```py
from collections import Counter
sets1 = [{1},{2},{1}]
Counter([tuple(a) for a in sets1])
```

Comment: `is` testing is unrelated to hashability.  Lack of hashability is not the reason np.unique() doesn't work on sets: according to the accepted answer, lack of total ordering is that reason.  Using tuple() on sets doesn't guarantee output ordering, so two sets with the same elements might incorrectly get converted to different tuples.