# Numpy unique keeps the first duplicate

Tags: python, numpy, duplicates, unique

I'm trying to use numpy's unique function. I'm seeing something strange:

```
import numpy as np
test =  [{"a"}, {"b"}, {"b"}, {"a"}]

print(test)
# [{'a'}, {'b'}, {'b'}, {'a'}]

u = np.unique(test)
print(u)
# [{'a'} {'b'} {'a'}]

print(u[0] == u[2])
# True
```

Why is it not removing the duplicate "a", like it did for "b"? It seems to be whichever is in the first position does not get removed.
What am I missing? It feels like a bug but I can't find anything online. I'm using numpy==1.19.4 on Ubuntu 20.04. I tried 1.19.5 (latest) but it still behaved this way.

Comment: This thread seems to answer the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977212/numpy-unique-gives-wrong-output-for-list-of-sets
Does this help?

Comment: yes, thank you, it only occurred to me later that using sets might be the issue here... thanks!